# I want to add new column on the basis of another column data in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, append

I have multiple csv file which i merged together after that in order to identify individual csv data in all merged csv file i wish to create a new column in pandas where the new column should be called serial.

I want a new column serial in the pandas and it should me numbered on the basis of data in Sequence column (For example-111111111,2222222222,33333333 for every new one in csv ).I had Attached snapshot of csv file also.

```
Sequence Number
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
1
2
3
4
```

I want output Like this-

```
Serial  Sequence Number
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   4
1   5
2   1
2   2
3   1
3   2
3   3
3   4
```

Comment: How did you merge the data from the different csv files? You can use the file name as an identifier. Place the outcome of the read function in a dictionary with file names as keys and data frames as values. Then  `df = pandas.concat(dict_of_df, sort=True)` will give you a data frame with file names in index.

Comment: See also answers to the question [Import multiple csv files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57608977/2641825)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) for column in first position filled with boolean mask for compare by `1` with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) (`==`) and cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df.insert(0, 'Serial', df['Sequence Number'].eq(1).cumsum())
print (df)
    Serial  Sequence Number
0        1                1
1        1                2
2        1                3
3        1                4
4        1                5
5        2                1
6        2                2
7        3                1
8        3                2
9        3                3
10       3                4
```